# Ajax Django 404 not found

Tags: django, ajax

could someone help me find a way to make my ajax request work?
Also, I'd be really thankful if someone explained to me what does success: function(data){} do.

So basically, I'm trying to update my cart using ajax, but I get an error
"jquery.min.js:2 GET http://192.168.1.17:8000/product/test_product-1/add_to_cart?productId=4&action=add&inputVal=4 404 (Not Found)"

All tutorials seem to use URL, but I'm using paths in my urls.py, could that be an issue?

I'm using the latest Django version.
I have never used ajax, so I don't really know what I'm doing. Please help:)

```
$('.update-cart').click(function(){
    var productId = $(this).attr("data-product");
    var action = $(this).attr("data-action");
    var pack = parseInt($(this).attr("data-pack"));

    try {
        var inputVal = parseInt(document.getElementById("quantity").value);
        if (inputVal%pack != 0){
            inputVal += pack - inputVal%pack
        }
    } catch {
        var inputVal = pack
    }

    $.ajax(
    {
        type:"GET",
        url: "add_to_cart",
        data:{
             productId: productId,
             action: action,
             inputVal: inputVal,
        },
        success: function( data )
        {
            $( '#like'+ productId ).remove();
            $( '#message' ).text(data);
        }
     })
});
```

this is my urls.py code:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('add_to_cart/', views.addToCart, name='add_to_cart'),
...
]
```

and this is my view:

```
def addToCart(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        productId = request.GET['productId']
        action = request.GET['action']
        quantity = request.GET['inputVal']

        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        addItem = Product.objects.get(id=productId)  # getting the added product
        orderItem = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(product=addItem)

        if action == 'add':
            orderItem.quantity += quantity
        elif action == 'remove':
            orderItem.quantity = (orderItem.quantity - orderItem.product.pack)
        elif action == 'removeAll':
            orderItem.quantity = 0

        orderItem.save()  # saving it to store in database

        if orderItem.quantity <= 0:
            orderItem.delete()

        return HttpResponse("Success! Item has been added")  # Sending an success response
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Request method is not a GET")
```

I have imported ajax to the base.html

```
...
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a forward slash in the start and the end of your url.

So it must be:

```
url: "/add_to_cart/"
```

Comment: it still says page not found 404, I have already tried that.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/handling-ajax-request-in-django/ i have followed these instructions

Comment: @Son, try this `url: "/add_to_cart/"`

Comment: I mean I changed the quotation marks to '/add_to_cart/' and it works now. It works now, but thanks

Comment: @Son, 404 not found has nothing to do with quotes. It has to do with the backslash in your url.

Comment: You mean a forward slash @NKSM

Comment: @DavidBrossard, yeah. Thanks for the correcting me.